# Filtering a DB across multiple cols trying to include null with like

Tags: sql

```
SELECT [columns]  
FROM [db] 
WHERE [c1] IN 'A' 
  AND [c2] IN 'B, C' 
  AND [c3] LIKE (X and Null)...
```

c3 is currently an array, though could be converted to binary flags but I need to include null entries as well as LIKE matches.

Essentially, I'm trying to filter an existing table across multiple values (11 columns).
When I use an OR statement for [c3], I get extra results that are outside the other filter terms.  Using an AND statement with LIKE is too restrictive, unless it could also include null entries in [c3].  All the other elements work except this one, because I had to leave [c3] as an array due to overlapping flags.

Comment: All columns are in the same DB and table, looks like I mislabeled [db] should be [table] there.

Comment: What do you mean with "`c3` is an array"? Can you show sample data?

Comment: c3 has data like:
a
a, b
b
b, c
and nulls as well

Comment: Found a better way, ended up filling in the null entries with a string to add to the search querry.

Answer (score 2):

This could have been accomplished without adding the strings (and more storage).

```
SELECT [columns] 
From [db] 
WHERE [c1] IN 'A' 
  AND [c2] IN 'B, C' 
  AND ([c3] LIKE 'X' OR [c3] IS NULL)
```